# Cheerio: find tag with multiple specific criteria easily and elegantly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to web scrape https://liquipedia.net/dota2/Admiral this page for all the `<li>` tags that are inside an `<ul>` tag that again is within a div with class `mw-parser-output` that has the `title` property. (I think that is what they're called in the HTML world? Like `<tag property="...">`).

What would be the most elegant, simple way to do this with Cheerio? I know I could do this with some for loops and stuff, but if there was a simple way to do this, my code would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure glad Cheerio is like jQuery. A simple selector like this should do:

```js
const li = $('div.mw-parser-output > ul > li[title]').toArray(); // Optionaly turn selected items into an array
```

Explanation of the CSS selector:

1. `div.mw-parser-output` `div` makes sure the element is that. The dot signifies that the selector is a `class`.
2. `>` Points to the immediate child
3. `ul` Simple `ul` tag
4. `li[title]` Any `li` tag, but it needs to have the title attribute.

Then we turn the result into an array so it become usable.
It's a simple as that.

You could also get an array of the text of each `li` element with the following:

```js
const arrayOfLiTexts = li.map($el => $el.text());
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However, when I meant with the property `title`, I did mean the `<li>`, not the `<div>`. I assume I just put the `[title]` behind the li instead though, so this was still a great answer for me! I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure! I edited the answer to match your description.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
const elements = $('div[title].mw-parser-output ul li').toArray();
```

Comment: OP didn't mention the element that is directly under the elements, but we both have answers that can help which I think is neato!